# perform a new task when android screen rotate

Tags: android

i created table view in android. at stable android screen it look like to 5 column and related the data of it...
but i want to add another 3 column when android rotate... it is possible??
how??

thanks in advance...

Comment: you can add the landscape layout xml in the layout-land folder. This xml will be called by android when the orientation changes to landscape.

Comment: good point. added to answer with clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u want to fix landscape view on perticular activity thn u hve add android:screenOrientation="landscape" into ur manifiest file..

eg:

```
activity android:name=".Classname" android:screenOrientation="landscape" 

========================

and if u want to do diffrent in Landscape or Portrait view thn u have to use
following into starting of ur onCreate() method.

if (this.getResources (). getConfiguration (). orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

              //== add view or action u want to perform

}
else if (this.getResources (). getConfiguration (). orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

            //== add view or action u want to perform
}
```

okay...!!

Comment: okay..now try "classname.this.getResources ()" instead of "this.getResources ()"

Answer (score 1):

When you rotate the device, the activity is restarted. You can save your current state (if needed) and just check in the oncreate if you are rotated.

Then you can add (or remove) the columns.

You could also look into [onConfigurationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges). like so:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  yourFunctionThatDoesColumnMagic();
}
```

Be sure to add to your manifest.xml the code for not restarting when you change in that case.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

a good point is made in the comments: you can indeed make a layout-land xml, but remember that you still have to call `setContentView()` again when something changes in one of the above mentioned methods!

Comment: can i implement on create method or another method??

Comment: Eeuhm, I don't know what you mean... If you don't put the configChanges in the manifest your activity will be recreated, so you can adress your issues in the oncreate. If you DO add them because you probably don't need to restart the activity, you need to adress the issues in the onconfigchanged.

Comment: give me an example so that can i implement.